# how to add tab item in one user control from another window + WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have one Parent window WMain, with a UserControl(Dashboard) inside a Stackpanel. In the Dashboard, I am have a Tabcontrol which will be populated on a button Click of a Button in the same Dashboard. The TabItem for Dashboard is another UserControl (uscEstimate). I am populating the TabControl with the below mentioned code

```
        TabItem Tab = new TabItem();
        Tab.Header = est;
        tbcMain.Items.Add(Tab);
        uscEstimate estimate = new uscEstimate();
        Tab.Content = new uscEstimate();
        Tab.Focus();
```

It is working fine. I want to add another TabItem into Dashboard on Button click of Estimate Usercontrol. Is there are way to create a TabItem of Parent UserControl from Child.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [EventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx).  You can use it to `publish` and `subscribe` an `event` notification and pass optional arguments (your `UserControl` in this scenario).

**uscEstimate.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public partial class uscEstimate : UserControl
{
    // Declare an EventHandler delegate that we will use to publish and subscribe to our event
    // We declare this as taking a UserControl as the event argument
    // The UserControl will be passed along when the event is raised
    public EventHandler<UserControl> AddNewItemEventHandler;

    public uscEstimate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Create a new UserControl and raise (publish) our event
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = new uscEstimate();
        RaiseAddNewItemEventHandler(control);
    }

    // We use this to raise (publish) our event to anyone listening (subscribed) to the event
    private void RaiseAddNewItemEventHandler(UserControl ucArgs)
    {
        var handler = AddNewItemEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, ucArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public sealed partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CreateAndAddTabItem("MainWindow");
    }

    // This manages the creation and addition of new tab items to the tab control
    // It also sets up the subscription to the event in the uscEstimate control
    private void CreateAndAddTabItem(string header)
    {
        var tab = new TabItem { Header = header };
        tbcMain.Items.Add(tab);
        var uscEstimate = new uscEstimate();
        uscEstimate.AddNewItemEventHandler += AddNewItemEventHandler;
        tab.Content = uscEstimate;
        tab.Focus();
    }

    // This handles the raised AddNewItemEventHandler notifications sent from uscEstimate
    private void AddNewItemEventHandler(object sender, UserControl userControl)
    {
        this.CreateAndAddTabItem("uscEstimate");
    }
}
```

I have omitted the `xaml` for this as the controls I used should be obvious from the code, however, should you require it I can provide it.